# Combine data from two tables into one output SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have two tables, as below:

[image: Inputs and result]

I'm hoping to create a view, where the result is as per the result above. That is, the Act column is the total of all matching records between tbl1 and tbl2.

Additional explaination, graphically:

[image]

Comment: You're looking for `JOIN` and aggregate functions (specifically `SUM`). What have you tried so far? Please do share your attempts so we can show you where you might have gone wrong, or not quite got it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd left join `tbl1` with an aggregate query on `tbl2`:

```
SELECT    t1.id, t1.req, COALESCE(t2.act, 0) AS act
FROM      tbl1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   id, SUM(act)
           FROM     tbl2
           GROUP BY id) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```